# I have two businesses. separating out the two gmail accounts

Tags: gmail

I am a real estate agent with Weichert Realtors.  I also operate a financial services company from a different location. When I type in my Financial services company  , my Weichert gmail account comes up. How do I correct that and establish a new  gmail account for my financial services company

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Gear" icon and select "Mail Settings." Click the "Multiple Inboxes" tab to customize the new inbox. Select which messages are displayed in the inbox, then click "Save Changes."